# Duda sobre la correcta interpretación de una expresión en C++

Tags: c++

Contexto:
Estaba intentando hacer un ejercicio del libro "el lenguaje de programación C++" en la página 113 capítulo 3: "expresiones y enunciados" (Bjarne Stroustrup, 2da edición, 1991, editorial Addison Wesley).
En particular dicho ejercicio es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo unas dudas respecto a la expresión que marqué en rojo.
En particular, como se puede apreciar en la imagen hay un "-" que es más largo que el otro, quiero saber si eso les parece que es un error de impresión y quisieron poner "--" o si era llanamente "-".
Lo que me hace pensar que puede ser que hubieran querido poner "--" es esta otra expresión que aparece en la siguiente página del libro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Que yo sepa no existe un operador "-" unario posfijo, así que por eso (y porque es más largo que un "-" normal que aparece en otras partes del libro) intuyo que debe ser un "--", y, por eso, creo que en la otra expresión también habían querido poner un "--".
Suponiendo que la expresión que quisieron poner entonces fuera:

`a = - 1 + + b - - - 5`

Sinceramente no me imagino como serían los paréntesis correctos para esta expresión.Teniendo en cuenta el orden de precedencia y asociatividad de operadores, según mi razonamiento sería:

`a = - (1 + + (b (- - (- 5))))`

Ya que son todos operadores con la misma precedencia y son unarios (por tanto asociativos a la derecha). Pero no tiene absolutamente ningún sentido la expresión así armada. Esto no significa nada (por ejemplo) la parte:

`b (- - (- 5))`

Ni idea que podría significar eso. Así que se me ocurrió que podría ser de esta otra forma:

`a = (((- 1) + (+ b)) - (- - 5))`

Pero tampoco tiene sentido, el operador "--" actúa sobre valor-i, y 5 no es un valor-i.

Suponiendo que el "-" largo es "-" y no "--" la expresión sería:

`a = - 1 + + b - - 5`

Y la interpretación que se me ocurrió es:
`a = (((- 1) + (+ b)) - (- 5))`
Que parece estar bien por las pruebas que hice, osea que es equivalente a `a = - 1 + + b - - 5`

Pero me quede pensando acerca de si el "-" largo ese es en realidad "--" y, en caso de ser así, como sería la correcta interpretación de dicha expresión.

Comment: Aunque ya hayas recibido respuesta, estaría muy bien que dejes la página por lo menos donde se encuentra el problema.

Comment: Uy, cierto. Perdón. Ahí la pongo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo encontré otra edición, y al parecer es como tu piensas, la linea larga representan 2 guiones `--`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se ve claramente que es `a = - 1 + + b - - - 5`

Y en el otro caso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí me pone que es `++a++` a diferencia de `++a--` de tu edición. Que para el caso de los paréntesis da lo mismo.

---

En mi opinión estos ejercicios son una tontera y pasaría de ellos, explico:

La importancia del orden de presendecia radica en no obtener resultados inesperados, tiene mucha relación a un problema que periodicamente se vuelve viral en internet: `6/2(1+2)=?`

Donde según coloquemos los paréntesis da resultados distintos:

- `(6/2)(1+2) = 9`
- `6/(2(1+2)) = 1`

Cual es resultado correcto? Bueno depende de donde coloques los paréntesis y donde colocar los paréntesis depende de la lógica de negocio que estemos aplicando a esa ecuación. Es decir responde a la situación particular de porque necesitamos realizar esa operación.

Caso muy distinto es colocar paréntesis para evitar un error de compilación, este caso tiene poca importancia porque el compilador nos advierte del problema. Este sería el caso del segundo ejercicio

- `++a++` No compila
- `++(a++)` No compila
- `(++a)++` Si compila (en algunos compiladores, lo que no me parece muy correcto, pero así es)

Pero en el caso del primer ejercicio tenemos `a = - 1 ++ b -- - 5`
Para que compile debería ser algo como `b = a = -1 + (+b--) - 5;` pero estamos separando el operador `++` que es UN operador (no 2 juntos), pero por otro lado ya sabemos que el libro contiene errores de impresión, por lo que nunca vamos a estar 100% seguros de que es lo real o no, entonces que hacemos?? Mejor continuar con el próximo capitulo

Comment: "Caso muy distinto es colocar paréntesis para evitar un error de compilación, este caso tiene poca importancia porque el compilador nos advierte del problema. Este sería el caso del segundo ejercicio"
Ah, tenía entendido que tanto la idea del segundo y sexto ejercicio era que supiera la correcta interpretación de las expresiones en C++. Osea, por ejemplo, que *p++ significa *(p++). Más que nada me base en los ejemplos que da en partes del capítulo para intuir que ese era el objetivo del ejercicio. No poner los paréntesis de forma que no de errores de compilación.

Comment: Digo, más que nada porque de los dos ejercicios solo las expresiones "++a++" y "a = - 1 ++ b -- - 5" requieren paréntesis pare evitar errores de compilación. 
"(++a)++ Si compila (en algunos compiladores, lo que no me parece muy correcto, pero así es)". Recién que lo mencionas me hace ruido, ¿hay algún objeto tal que si le aplicas el operador de incremento quede un valor-i? Porque si no independientemente de qué sea "a" esa expresión va a dar error ¿cierto?, ¿es esa la razón por la que no te parece muy correcto?

Comment: (haciendo referencia a la pregunta de si hay algún objeto tal que si le aplicas el operador ++ quede un valor-i)
Me refiero más allá de alguna sobrecarga de operadores que puedas hacer en un tipo definido por el usuario.

Comment: En el tema de las precedencias, no es que uno se sepa la tabla de memoria, porque rápidamente te das cuenta que la forma correcta es escribir una expresión larga es en varias líneas (no todo junto en una sola), por ejemplo el típico problema de `a = x - ++x` eso debería haberse escrito en 2 líneas de código. Entonces, separar la expresión hace un código más legible y menos propenso a errores, y eventualmente olvidas esa tabla de precedencia, porque nunca caes en un problema. Yo el tema de los punteros lo he olvidado completamente, pero no estoy muy seguro de que *p++ significa *(p++)

Comment: Me parece raro que me haya compilado el  `(++a)++`, porque podemos definir la operación `++a`  como: "incrementa el `a` en 1 y devuelve su *valor* incrementado", entonces si devuelve un valor (no una referencia) como podemos seguir incrementando? porque lo que ahora tenemos sencillamente es un número y no una variable, es como hacer directamente `5++`. Ante la duda probé esto mismo en otros 2 lenguajes (javascript y c#) en ambos no fue posible realizar esta operación

Comment: No entendí a que te refieres con `valor-i`, pero prueba esto `int a=2147483647; int b=++a;` y luego mira el número almacenado en `b`

Comment: De todas formas hago un descargo de responsabilidad, desde la universidad (muuuchos años atrás) que no toco C++. Mi opinión es la de una persona que lleva muchos años programando pero en otros lenguajes. Entonces lo que me parece extraño, quizás no lo sea en el esotérico mundo de C++

Comment: "que la forma correcta es escribir una expresión larga es en varias líneas...Entonces, separar la expresión hace un código más legible y menos propenso a errores".
Esa recomendación es la misma que también da en el libro. En el libro dice: "El empleo de paréntesis se hace más común conforme las subexpresiones se vuelven más complicadas, pero las subexpresiones complicadas son una fuente de errores. Por tanto, si el programador comienza a sentir que hacen falta paréntesis, podría pensar en descomponer la expresión utilizando una variable adicional".

Comment: "pero no estoy muy seguro de que *p++ significa *(p++)". Bueno, e ahí un buen ejemplo de porque esta bueno saber el orden de precedencia  y asociatividad (más o menos). Hay dos razones por las cuales sé que esa es la correcta interpretación de esa expresión: porque son operadores con la misma precedencia y son operadores unarios (por tanto asociativos de derecha a izquierda). Y por ejemplo hubiera quedado medio raro poner esa expresión tan corta en 2 líneas o ponerle paréntesis (que se puede).

Comment: Sí, ya sé. Es relativa la utilidad de ver esto (tema precedencia y asociatividad). Pero en mi caso particular (por filosofía propia) prefiero centrarme en un solo lenguaje de programación y conocerlo a fondo en vez de a varios por arriba. Y este lenguaje se usa en todas las cosas que me importan. Esto es parte de conocerlo lo más posible. Y si bien, ciertamente, uno mismo podría ponerle paréntesis a todo y así no hay necesidad de saber como funciona ni la precedencia ni la asociatividad, si empezas a hacer eso las expresiones terminan quedando con demasiados paréntesis demasiado pronto.

Comment: O expresiones simples partidas en demasiadas variables adicionales. Y además si estás leyendo código escrito por otro no tenes garantía de que esa otra persona tenga la costumbre de partir las expresiones en muchas partes, y te costaría entender ese código. Además la reglas de precedencia y asociatividad en c++ parece que no cambian desde 1991, así que me imagino que tarde o temprano me las acabaré acordando.

Comment: Claramente si usas 10 lenguajes distintos y c++ es "uno más", no vale la pena el esfuerzo (saber eso de los operadores me refiero, también porque por lo general las expresiones funcionan como se espera salvo contados casos)

Comment: "Me parece raro que me haya compilado el (++a)++, porque podemos definir la operación ++a como: "incrementa el a en 1 y devuelve su valor incrementado", entonces si devuelve un valor (no una referencia) como podemos seguir incrementando?". Ah, tiene sentido. ¿Entonces el único caso en el que esa expresión tiene sentido que compile sería cuando tenemos un operador "++" sobrecargado que sí devuelve un valor-i?

Comment: "No entendí a que te refieres con valor-i". En principio un valor-i es cualquier valor que puede estar a la izquierda de una asignación (aunque hay excepciones). Por cierto en inglés sería lvalue ( por las dudas que estés más familiarizado con ese término).

Comment: "quizás no lo sea en el esotérico mundo de C++". Estaba a punto de decirte que c++ no es esotérico pero acabo de buscar bien la definición de esotérico. Y tenés razón XD

Comment: ahh lvalue, ese término me suena más y claro que tiene que ver.  El operador incremento necesita un LValue y retorna un RValue, por eso no debería ser posible aplicar 2 veces consecutivas un incremento